# Render other view without loosing variable values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, redirect

I have a helpers in Rails app that return some data based on a variable set in controller: like:

```rb
def title
    base_title = "Unikernel"
    if @title.nil? then
        base_title
    else
        "#{base_title} | #{@title}"
    end
end
```

And in controller (usually in each action) I set the value, eg:

```rb
@title = "Solutions"
```

now when I process some result I get from form submission, if something's wrong I say:

```rb
render action: "edit"
```

or

```rb
render "new"
```

When I'm on the rendered page the variables aren't initialized and so on.

What should I do with this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, when something is wrong while updating, you find yourself in the update action. When something goes wrong while creating, your error message gets shown by the create action. Did you set your variable in your create and update action, too?

```
def new
  @title = "New page"
end

def create
  @title = "Errors!"
end
```

When you submit your form and get errors, you will get `@title` from your `create` action and if you haven't set it in create, `@title` will be nil.

**When you call `render`, you are not redirecting to another action, hence you are still in `update`.**

Comment: Yes, It's a good idea, thank you! Also I've found that I can use initializing method with `before_filter` if I need the same data through all resource.

Comment: You're welcome! Good idea, a before filter will help you keep your code DRY :)